# Rails not recognizing true or false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I have something that should be really simple, but it's killing me.

```
l = LineItem.first
#<LineItem id: 5, product_id: 1, quantity: 1, price: #<BigDecimal:7f7fdb51a3f8,'0.999E3',9(18)>, cart_id: 5, discount_percentage: 10, discount_amount: nil, discount_active: true, created_at: "2012-01-12 16:17:41", updated_at: "2012-01-12 16:17:41">
```

I have

```
l.discount_percentage.blank?
=> false
```

So, I have the following method:

```
  def total_price
    discount_amount = 0 if discount_amount.blank?
    discount_percentage = 0 if discount_percentage.blank?

    discounted_amount_from_percent = price*(discount_percentage.to_f/100)

    applicable_discount = [discount_amount,discounted_amount_from_percent].max

    return (price-applicable_discount)
  end
```

But when I do this:

```
l.total_price
```

Instead of returning 899, it returns 999 (meaning that the if discount_percentage.blank? didn't work at all!)

Or the syntax WHATEVER_HERE if true/false only work in the View on Rails??

Comment: The postfix conditional (`do_something if condition`) is valid Ruby syntax, and isn't restricted to the view.

Comment: What happens if you use `self.discount_percentage` instead?

Comment: Dave, that works, but the issue is:

If price is accessible without the self.price, why I need to have self on discount_amount and discount_percentage???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here lays the problem:

```
discount_amount = 0 if discount_amount.blank?
discount_percentage = 0 if discount_percentage.blank?
```

Ruby "sees" variables from top to bottom and from left to right, so in that line he first sees a local variable (`discount_amount =`) so he decides this `discount_amount` thing in `discount_mount.blank?` is that same local variable (and not the instance method. You think the variable is not defined yet, but Ruby has already spotted it). Not having any value yet, `discount_amount`it set to default value `nil`, so `nil.blank?` succeeds and the assignment `discount_percentage = 0` is made. Ditto for `discount_percentage`. Here's a demo snippet:

```
class ExampleClass 
  def run
    x = "it works as expected" if x == "x"
    x
  end

  def run2
    if x == "x"
      x = "it works as expected" 
    end
    x
  end

  def run3
    xy = "it works as expected" if x == "x"
    xy
  end

  def x; "x"; end
end

p ExampleClass.new.run #=> nil
p ExampleClass.new.run2 #=> "it works as expected"
p ExampleClass.new.run3 #=> "it works as expected"
```

Step 1: don't use the same names for local variables and instance methods. That's usually a bad idea anyway because you lose track of which one you are using, but in this case it has really bitten you.

Step 2: Do not write imperative code when you're doing math calculations! Really, maths (9X % of the things you do in a typical application, (10-X)% being unavoidable side-effects) play well with [expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), not with statements. I'd write:

```
def total_price
  final_discount_amount = discount_amount || 0
  final_discount_percentage = discount_percentage || 0
  discounted_amount_from_percent = price * (final_discount_percentage.to_f/100)
  applicable_discount = [final_discount_amount, discounted_amount_from_percent].max
  price - applicable_discount
end
```

Comment: Your explanation is EXCELLENT.

The method is much cleaner. But I'm a beginner that's why my methods are all imperative including the calcs. It's closer to human language.

Answer (score 1):

When using attribute writers (e.g `foo = ...`), you should use `self` explicitly. This is nicely explained [here](http://www.rubyfleebie.com/use-self-explicitly/).

So your code should be like this:

```
 def total_price
    self.discount_amount = 0 if discount_amount.blank?
    self.discount_percentage = 0 if discount_percentage.blank?

    # local var, self not necessary
    discounted_amount_from_percent = price*(discount_percentage.to_f/100)

    # local var, self not necessary
    applicable_discount = [discount_amount,discounted_amount_from_percent].max

    return (price-applicable_discount)
  end
```

This is also [explained](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html) in the *Programming Ruby* book:

> Why did we write `self.leftChannel` in the example on page 74? Well,
>   there's a hidden gotcha with writable attributes. Normally, methods
>   within a class can invoke other methods in the same class and its
>   superclasses in functional form (that is, with an implicit receiver of
>   `self`). However, this doesn't work with attribute writers. Ruby sees
>   the assignment and decides that the name on the left must be a local
>   variable, not a method call to an attribute writer.