# Ruby knows 'myvar' is a variable in myvar = 0 if false

Tags: ruby, variables, methods, declaration

I'm learning Ruby and I like playing with `irb` to discover new features and tricks.  Today I was playing with variables and methods because I wanted to know which one took preference in front of the other one.  Everything looked fine until I tried this:

```
def test
   puts "hello"
end

test = "bye" if false

puts test
```

I was expecting this to return `"hello"` , but it doesn't.  So, I suppose the parser is treating 'test' as a **variable** instead of as a **method**.  I have two questions:

1. Is my assumption correct?
2. Is there any way to know if *something* is a variable or a method? Some method like `test.is_variable?`

Comment: Even without the `test = "bye" if false` line, the code would return `hello` `nil` because the `test` method returns the result of puts("hello") which is `nil`.

Comment: @GoodEnough You are right. I tried it too without the "puts".  Thanks for the comment though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
test = "hello" if false
p test #=> nil
```

The local variable `test` is created anyway (with default value `nil`), and given that local variables overshadow methods with the same name, that's the value you get. Just an hour ago [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838700/rails-not-recognizing-true-or-false) got bitten by a subtle variation of the theme. And don't you think this only happens with one-liner conditionals:

```
if false
  test = "hello" 
end
p test #=> nil
```

That's because Ruby defines variables when they are parsed (and not when they are executed).

Comment: Local variables get defined at parse time. There's really nothing more  to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two methods that help: `methods` and `local_variables`. I wouldn't recommend using them in real world programs, but they might be useful when learning Ruby.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "there are at least two methods that help" ?

Comment: There are others, e.g. `private_methods`, `public_methods`, `global_variables` etc. if you are wondering about "at least two".

Comment: Are local variables considered methods too? That's what I am surprised.